# Can I get a mobile phone contract if I am unemployed?

Tags: credit, unemployment, mobile-phone-plans

Can I get a mobile phone contract if I am unemployed?

Answer (score 3):

That is really up to the provider as to what hurdles they decide to make you jump.

I don't recall being asked for my employment status, but I suspect they might have done a credit check.

Alternately; you could go with a pay-as-you-go phone.